# I'm trying to plot a polygon with a hover text on google map

Tags: python, json, polygon, geopandas

I'm plotting a polygon with hover text , but its showing polygon is not serializable into JSON.

```
hover_text1="this is simple"
l=gmaps.MarkerOptions(hover_text=hover_text1)
drawing = gmaps.drawing_layer(
 features=[map_polygon,l] 
 # show_controls=False
 )
```

Expected output is polygon with hover text ,but its showing error:

> TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable